# HTML, CSS page alignment issue

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a news website. I am not getting what actually I'm doing wrong on this page. I tried but failed to find what's wrong with this page.

```css
#news-outer {
  margin: 0px;
  max-width: 58%;
  max-height: 700px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.news-pic {
  width: 100%;
  height: 225px;
}

.news-pic img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.news-heading {
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  white-space: initial;
}

.news-content {
  display: none;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 8px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: initial;
  border: 1px solid #8dc2e8;
}

.toggle-news-content {
  float: right;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".toggle-news-content").click(function() {
      $(this).prev(".news-content").fadeToggle(300);
      if ($(this).text() == "More...") {
        $(this).text("...Less");
        $(this).title = "Press to read less article";
      } else
        $(this).text("More...");
    });
  });
</script>
<div id="news-outer" style="background-color: black">
  <div style="max-height: auto;">
    <div class="news-pic" style="background-color: red"><img src="Cricket-Game.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="news-heading" style="background-color: blue">heading of news 1</div>
    <div class="news-content" style="background-color: yellow" class="news-content">content of news 1 </div>
    <a href="#" class="toggle-news-content" style="background-color: purple" title="Press to read full article">More...</a>
  </div>
  <div style="max-height: auto;">
    <div class="news-pic" style="background-color: greenyellow"><img src="11.jpeg" /></div>
    <div class="news-heading" style="background-color: orange">heading of news 2</div>
    <div class="news-content" style="background-color: green" class="news-content">content of news 2</div>
    <a href="#" class="toggle-news-content" style="background-color: purple" title="Press to read full article">More...</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the output is:

[image: output]

The "heading of news 1" is at its right position, but as you can see "heading of news 2" is overriding the picture, it's supposed to be like "heading of news 1". Can anyone of you tell me what actually wrong in this code?

Comment: Are there any additional CSS rules being applied to the header in your output?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add a `clear:both` to your articles. Without it, the "more" button (which is *floated*), overflows the article's content and pushes the image from the next article to the bottom.

Working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Shitsu/t25hkh75/.

(I just added a `news` class to your html and a CSS rule)

Answer (score 0):

You could also try to add `overflow: hidden;` to `.news-pic`. Also note that your images get warped in the markup setup you use. To fix it, you could use so called "[padding-trick](https://css-tricks.com/scaled-proportional-blocks-with-css-and-javascript/)".

```
.news-pic {
    width: 100%;
    height: 225px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".toggle-news-content").click(function() {
      $(this).prev(".news-content").fadeToggle(300);
      if ($(this).text() == "More...") {
        $(this).text("...Less");
        $(this).title = "Press to read less article";
      } else
        $(this).text("More...");
    });
  });
```

```css
#news-outer {
  margin: 0px;
  max-width: 58%;
  max-height: 700px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.news-pic {
  width: 100%;
  height: 225px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.news-pic img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.news-heading {
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  white-space: initial;
}

.news-content {
  display: none;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 8px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: initial;
  border: 1px solid #8dc2e8;
}

.toggle-news-content {
  float: right;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="news-outer" style="background-color: black">
  <div style="max-height: auto;">
    <div class="news-pic" style="background-color: red"><img src="http://i.imgci.com/espncricinfo/GAMES/featuredGame_22_06.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="news-heading" style="background-color: blue">heading of news 1</div>
    <div class="news-content" style="background-color: yellow" class="news-content">content of news 1 </div>
    <a href="#" class="toggle-news-content" style="background-color: purple" title="Press to read full article">More...</a>
  </div>
  <div style="max-height: auto;">
    <div class="news-pic" style="background-color: greenyellow"><img src="http://i.imgci.com/espncricinfo/GAMES/featuredGame_22_06.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="news-heading" style="background-color: orange">heading of news 2</div>
    <div class="news-content" style="background-color: green" class="news-content">content of news 2</div>
    <a href="#" class="toggle-news-content" style="background-color: purple" title="Press to read full article">More...</a>
  </div>
</div>
```